# Firebase analytics gets disabled when updating firebase sdk to 6.2.0 or higher

Tags: ios, objective-c

Firebase Analytics stops working when updating the Firebase Core iOS SDK to 6.2.0 or higher versions.

Works fine if the version is 6.1.0 or lower.

[FIRApp configure];

Gets the following logs in console

```
6.10.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS034002] Failed to recreate database file. Error: Error Domain=com.google.gmp.measurement.ErrorDomain Code=3 "Database operation "prepare statement" failed with sqlite code 0 and error message "not an error"" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Database operation "prepare statement" failed with sqlite code 0 and error message "not an error", APMMonitorContext=prepare statement,0,A,3}

6.10.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS012001] Failed to open database (Init)

6.10.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS034002] Failed to recreate database file. Error: Error Domain=com.google.gmp.measurement.ErrorDomain Code=3 "Database operation "prepare statement" failed with sqlite code 0 and error message "not an error"" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Database operation "prepare statement" failed with sqlite code 0 and error message "not an error", APMMonitorContext=prepare statement,0,A,3}

6.10.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS012001] Failed to open database (Init)

6.10.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023011] Failed to start Analytics. Analytics is disabled
```

Comment: I had a similar problem with Firebase. Do you use SQLCipher in your project? If yes, yo need to upgrade SQLCipher with its latest version. It's simple. https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/ios-tutorial/